# What are the advantages of keeping the cacerts file at a location outside JRE?

Tags: java, ssl

I have a cacerts file at the location (`/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_29/jre/lib/security/cacerts`) and hence my java app searches for the keystore file at this location.

However considering that my java version is very old and that the cacerts file gets updated with CA root certificates only when the JRE is upgraded which is quite rare (depending on the dev priorities) what I understand is that my java app would be affected when some external 3rd party introduces new 3rd party certificates which are not present in my cacerts file.

So upon looking at the several options I found that I need to use the property -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore and set its value to the location of my cacerts file outside the JRE . So that the application would search for the cacerts file outside the JRE and then reference it to my default cacerts file.

So my question is to why do that? what is the advantage of keeping it outside JRE (to make it independent of JRE ?)

As it becomes independent of JRE will it not look for new 3rd party root certificates and hence my JAVA application would not be affected?

Or it has to do something with the property 'javax.net.ssl.trustStore'.

I have already referred to [this](http://fusesource.com/docs/broker/5.3/security/SSL-SysProps.html) .

But could someone please make me understand this as I am not getting a clear picture of this.

Comment: A keystore is "fixed"; once it is created, it is not modified unless you manuall modify it (using the appropriate tool). An external keystore allows you to customize the list of CAs you wish to deem as valid; it will have an effet on all `SSLSocket`s you create, in the sense that CAs not recognized by your keystore will prevent the connection from being established. However I feel there is more to it than what I have explained here...

Comment: So what i wanted to know is that if I am using some 3rd party CA certificates and they are present in my keystore, then things are fine. But if new certificates are introduced and they are not present in my Keystore using the property javax.net.ssl.trustStore would help from affecting my application even though my keystore doesnot have the new certificates...?

Comment: Well yes they are, as long as the keystore contains all the chain elements up to roots

Comment: So you mean all the certificates present in the certificate chain?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean. In a certificate, you have both the CN and the issuer. A "root certificate" is a certificate where the CN and issuer are the same.

Comment: Ok but when a new certificate is issued by the third party that would also be included in the certificate chain, so may be we need to periodically check for new certificates by making an ssl connection. Please correct if i am wrong

Answer (score 2):

The advantage is that it gives the user setting up this application complete control over that truststore. In particular, this is useful if:

- You need to use other CA certificates that are not in the default bundles (e.g. corporate CAs), but do not want to alter the default `cacerts` file: you might not have administrative access to this file, or you might not want to change this for other Java applications also using that JRE.
- You want to be stricter than the default list and remove some CAs you don't need and trust.

The disadvantages is that you need to review the CA list when some are removed following an incident.

Alternatively, you can also consider [using the platform's CA certificates](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/security-137537.html) if available in your environment (although `WINDOWS-ROOT` has a few bugs unfortunately).
Some Linux distribution also have [a separate CA bundle](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=ca-certificates-java).